# Simultaneous systems of equations with 2x2 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $2\times 2$-matrices, and considering the equation $$AX=B$$
Where $X$ is an unknown $2\times 2$-matrix. What I want to do is explain why the equation is equivalent to solving two $2\times 2$-systems of equations simultaneously and determine how this generalizes to $n\times n$.

And, on the corollary, let $A,B,C$ be three $2\times 2$-matrices and consider the equation $$AX+XB=C$$

What I want to do here explain why you can not solve this as two $2\times 2$-systems of equations simultaneously.

As for the first one, my logic would be to let $X=[x\ \ y]$ and $B=[b_1 \ \ b_2]$ where $x,y,b_1,b_2$ are 2D column vectors. It's rather easy to see that $Ax=b_1$ and $Ay=b_2$ in that case, but as for the rest, I really don't even know where to start, so if someone could give me some pointers, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AX+XB=C$.

$$\pmatrix{a&b\cr c&d\cr}\pmatrix{x&y\cr z&w\cr}+\pmatrix{x&y\cr z&w\cr}\pmatrix{e&f\cr g&h\cr}=\pmatrix{i&j\cr k&l\cr}$$

$ax+bz+ex+gy=i$; $ay+bw+fx+hy=j$; $cx+dz+ez+gw=k$; $cy+dw+fz+hw=l$.

$(a+e)x+gy+bz=i$; $fx+(a+h)y+bw=j$; $cx+(d+e)z+gw=k$; $cy+fz+(d+h)w=l$.

Each of these equations involves three of the four unknowns $x,y,z,w$; there is no way to split the four equations into pairs so that each pair involves only two of the unknowns.

For $AX=B$, with all being $n\times n$ matrices, let $x_i$ be the $i$th column of $X$, $1\le i\le n$, and let $b_i$ be the $i$th column of $B$; then $Ax_i=b_i$, so there's your $n$ systems of $n$ equations in $n$ unknowns.